# what cache settings would you recommend for me?

Tags: apache-2.2, cache

I'm looking for some sample code to get me started experimenting with cache control in Apache, with .htacces or httpd.conf.

Can anyone give me any code i can copy and paste in? (and then start tweaking on my own)

lets say i wanted to

> cache js,css,images for 30 days

not cache my html as it is fresh every few mins so

```
not cache anything ending in .php, .html or '/'
```

**I dont want this to look like i'm asking someone to do this for me,  - i'm just after some code i can start messing around with!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Konerak said you can use mod_expires, to enable it in a shell do:

```
# for ubuntu
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo service apache2 restart

# or, for other distros as root:
a2enmod expires
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

here's a vhost configuration that would certainly fit your needs:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    [...]

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 30 days"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 30 days"

    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything else should not be cached.

The script is an extract from my configuration for my website at http://www.codealpha.net/ you can see that it caches only images. (Javascript cache is not enabled.)

**Documentation:** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: cheers man, that's very kind of you. I've never done any vhosts stuff (or anything besides mode_rewrite and 301s) in apache.. does that just go in a htaccess file?

Comment: Yes you can try adding the "Expires" to the .htaccess (do not add the virtualhost tags). If it does not work, you will probably have to add the Expires to your configuration (probably httpd.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-available if using ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

use the [mod_expires from Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html). You should look into the ExpiresByType.

Comment: will it detect '/' as type:html? I'm still looking for an actual sample piece of code from someone's site (regardless of whether it does what i want) so i can see a 'complete' cache choice for a certain site

Comment: Types aren't determined by the requesting URL, they're determined by the document that is returned. So if you index is set to index.html, it'll pickup the extension on that file.

Answer (score 1):

ExpiresActive On

```
    # expire All after a month in the client's cache
    ExpiresDefault A2592000

    # HTML documents are good for a week from the time they were changed
    ExpiresByType text/html M604800
    ExpiresByType application/javascript M604800
    ExpiresByType text/javascript M604800
    ExpiresByType text/css M604800

    # Don't cache
        <FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
            ExpiresActive Off
        </FilesMatch>
```